# Uncaught ReferenceError in Google Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

This is my manifest file:

```
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"

  ],

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [ "jquery-3.4.1.min.js", "content.js" ]
    }
  ],
```

When I enter a website it should run the following js:

```
$(function () {
   alert("aa");
}
);
```

But whenever I enter a website Chrome gives this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Comment: typo: `jquey` should be `jquery`.

Comment: A good practice would be to enter developer tools and see console errors

Comment: thank wOxxOm you so much ı fixed it but error still continues to occur

Comment: stationary traveler thank you so much . ı looked at the developer tools ı found nothing ı deleted some files and rewrote them than the problem was solved

Comment: @ata, when you edit manifest.json or content script you need to reload the extension on `chrome://extensions` page and the web page tab too.